# VBS IF statement to replace text

Tags: vbscript

I have a database pointing config file that I would like to control with VBS.
Below I am trying to set the config file to point from database 1 to 3 out of 5 possible databases.

Example: this script below changes the config settings from database 1 to point to database 3

```
Option Explicit
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO,objFile,strText,strNewText
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\Live directory 1\test 1.txt",ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "<BaseUrl>https://test1-provident.saasloans.com</BaseUrl>", "<BaseUrl>https://test3-provident.saasloans.com</BaseUrl>")


Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\newtons\Desktop\Live directory 1\test 1.txt",ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
set objFSO = Nothing
set objFile = Nothing


MsgBox "satzorapp4 is now pointing to test3-provident.saasloans.com" ,0, ""
```

The above script is very restricted e.g. as others use the config file I will not know what database the config file is set to before running the VBS script  which is why I need the VBS script to take this into account using possibly IF/AND statements e.g.

```
IF (already set to 3 THEN ignore + msgbox "Pointing to database 3")
```

The last issue I have is e.g. If the config file is set to database two and my vbs script base line is looking for database one it will not work.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Can you share a sample of your config file, and then explain, in layman's terms, what you would want the script to do? Like "I want the script to tell me where the config file is pointing to by reading line one of the config, then I want to increment that server number by one and write it back to the config file".

Comment: Please note I cannot just increment the number by 1. The config file could be set to 1 of 5 possible settings as this is used by others so I need the script to overwrite the line of text that controls the mapping which is why I used the (poor) example in the code above - IF strtext = "server 2
Then = msgbox "Pointing to server 2" (So if the server is already pointing to server 2 the code is kept and a confirmation message displayed)

Comment: Rewritten VBS code above and changed wording to try and make it clear what I am trying to do.

Comment: you can use `Instr` to test for `test1-provident` or `test2-provident` or `test3-provident` for example, to find out which server its on.

Comment: Thanks, yes I can use this however I cannot find any examples that would help me - If Instr (test1-provident) Then "" I assume I there is an easier way to do this rather than writing the instr query x5 and writing variables

Comment: Use `RegEx` instead of `Instr` 5 times.